# How do I put on my resume that I am a backup to my managers?

Tags: resume, manager

I have no manager experience and I am looking to move up in my company. My manager left 3 months ago and I am applying for their job.  I want to say that I have been acting as their backup in their absence in my resume.

Comment: How did you end up at the arrangement where you "backup" your manager that left?  Did someone appoint you as an interim manager or did you unilaterally decide to do what your manager was doing?

Comment: I have always been the backup for days off, etc.  My department has 2 managers and a director who I support as an analyst.  When one manager left, the director split their work between me and the other manager.  I've been in my role for 3 years and am kind of a subject-matter expert for our team.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You aren't the "backup" any more because you are now doing the job.

> April 2022 - Present: Acting manager, Acme Corp
>
> Took over managerial responsibilities for the widgets team after the previous manager left the company. <add description of what manager things you did here>
>
> July 2019 - July 2022: <your job title>, Acme Corp
>
> <add description of what non-manager things you did here>. Also performed managerial tasks as above when the manager was unavailable.

Comment: Additionally, it helps to add focus with metrics indicating that the team is operating properly and in a position to advance as a result. Any metric on delivery will do that helps the new hiring manager understand that keeping OP in place is a huge savings and benefit to the team.

Comment: @JoelEtherton In theory, yes. In practice, the most important thing for someone in an acting manager role for three months is _not to break anything_.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. And metrics supporting that reinforce the argument.

Comment: "April 2022 - Present: Acting manager, Acme Corp. Number of things broken: 0"